# How to make environment variables work in a JAR file?

Tags: java, r, intellij-idea, jar, project

I am struggling with making RJava work in my Java program, as it seems to depend on the whole R directory tree to work. This directory tree is named $R_HOME in the system and, by configuring the project's environment variables, it points to `/usr/lib64/R`.

This works OK when I run my application on my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), but whenever I try to pack my code in a JAR and run it using `java -jar xxx.jar`, it will throw the following error:

```
R_HOME is not set. Please set all required environment variables before running this program.
Unable to start R
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f847c3a470c, pid=4232, tid=4233
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (10.0.2+13) (build 10.0.2+13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.2+13, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libR.so+0x17270c]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to /home/xvlaze/IdeaProjects/Ypsilon/out/artifacts/Ypsilon/core.4232)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/xvlaze/IdeaProjects/Ypsilon/out/artifacts/Ypsilon/hs_err_pid4232.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

That message was the one I was getting on the IDE while the R_HOME environment variable was not set. Seems either the JAR file can't read any environment variables or that I need to tell the project it has to include something I don't know.

Although I'm rooting for the first option, perhaps I am missing something as I am relatively new to Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplest solution is to run it as: `R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R java -jar xxx.jar`

This would set an environment variable named `R_HOME` for the execution of your jar

Comment: But what if I have to distribute that JAR to another machine? I would have a huge portability issue.

Comment: You can use a shellscript, or bring your own JRE using java packager ans set your environment variables there (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html)

Comment: I can't find ```javapackager``` in my system. I am using OpenJDK 10 and I think the Packager is Oracle exclusive. What shell script are you mentioning?

Comment: Javapackager is and Oracle JDK feature.

Comment: Any workaround? I'd rather not use Oracle JDK after the changes in the license, as my application is strictly for commercial use.

Comment: So I would advise you to go with a shellscript that would launch your application as per my original answer.

Comment: What if the application is run on Windows? Should I write shellscripts for every platform? The software is intended to be distributed.

Comment: That's a bigger problem. You need to think about compatiility to any Java version a user may have, or to distribute a JRE with your solution. I would look into launch4j, or other java wrappers. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I didn't know about that! I'm accepting your answer as the problem is broad and the original question is answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Run your app with -D argument:

```
java -DR_HOME="/path/to/some-dir" -jar xxx.jar
```

Quotes are important if R_HOME contains spaces or minuses.

Comment: But what if I have to distribute that JAR to another machine? I would have a huge portability issue.